# json explode - return filtered array of records

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I have some JSON I have exploded however I need to filter the return based on where the "locale" is en_GB and I only wish to return that data in the dataframe.

I currently have

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

jsonDF2 = jsonDF.withColumn('d', explode(col('d.picklistOptions.results.picklistLabels.results')))
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select(jsonDF2.d.optionId, jsonDF2.d.label,jsonDF2.d.locale).filter(array_contains(col("d.locale"), "en_GB")).show(10)
```

However this obviously does as it says it returns me the rows where en_GB is in locale but I actually only want it to return each row that was matching in tabular form.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|          d.optionId|             d.label|            d.locale|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[45024, 45024, 45...|[Theft the compan...|[en_GB, en_US, th...|
|[45046, 45046, 45...|[Back to home tow...|[th_TH, en_US, en...|
|[45031, 45031, 45...|[Non-confirmation...|[en_GB, en_US, th...|
|[45023, 45023, 45...|[Commit a serious...|[en_GB, en_US, th...|
|[45015, 45015, 45...|[Absence more tha...|[en_GB, en_US, th...|
|[45017, 45017, 45...|[Resignation, Res...|[th_TH, en_US, en...|
|[45039, 45039, 45...|[Be an alien, Be ...|[th_TH, en_US, en...|
|[45048, 45048, 45...|[Education, Educa...|[th_TH, en_US, en...|
|[45043, 45043, 45...|[Farming, Farming...|[th_TH, en_US, en...|
|[45040, 45040, 45...|[Death, Death, De...|[en_GB, en_US, th...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

So basically I would want just

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|          d.optionId|             d.label|            d.locale|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[45024              |[Theft the compan   |en_GB               |
|[45624              |[Back to home tow.. |en_GB               |
```

Where have I gone wrong? can someone please explain.

**Update**

I have changed the code to this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

jsonDF2 = jsonDF.withColumn('d', explode(col('d.picklistOptions.results.picklistLabels.results')))

jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select(explode(jsonDF2.d.optionId), jsonDF2.d.label,jsonDF2.d.locale).withColumnRenamed("col","optionId").distinct()
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select(jsonDF2.optionId, explode(jsonDF2.d.label),jsonDF2.d.locale).withColumnRenamed("col","label").distinct()
jsonDF2.show(100,truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|optionId|d.label                                                                                                                                                     |d.locale             |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|45995   |[ลาออก โอนย้ายระหว่างภาค, Resignation and Transfer across Region]                                                                                           |[th_TH, en_GB]       |
|45016   |[Absence after training No show, Absence after training No show, Absence after training No show]                                                            |[th_TH, en_US, en_GB]|
```

It then fails with

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'd'
```

But the column is called "d.label".

Dataframe Schema after initial explode.

```
root
 |-- d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- __metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- optionId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- picklistOption: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
```

This is how it looks after my initial select and explode the "optionId" as shown by your example.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

JSON Example

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/Picklist('cust_resignReason')",
            "type": "SFOData.Picklist"
        },
        "picklistId": "cust_resignReason",
        "picklistOptions": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistOption(45024L)",
                        "type": "SFOData.PicklistOption"
                    },
                    "id": "45024",
                    "minValue": "0",
                    "externalCode": null,
                    "maxValue": "0",
                    "optionValue": "-1",
                    "sortOrder": 10,
                    "mdfExternalCode": "Theft_(company)",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "parentPicklistOption": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistOption(45024L)/parentPicklistOption"
                        }
                    },
                    "picklistLabels": {
                        "results": [
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='en_GB',optionId=45024L)",
                                    "type": "SFOData.PicklistLabel"
                                },
                                "optionId": "45024",
                                "locale": "en_GB",
                                "id": "177967",
                                "label": "Theft the company property",
                                "picklistOption": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='en_GB',optionId=45024L)/picklistOption"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='en_US',optionId=45024L)",
                                    "type": "SFOData.PicklistLabel"
                                },
                                "optionId": "45024",
                                "locale": "en_US",
                                "id": "177968",
                                "label": "Theft the company property",
                                "picklistOption": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='en_US',optionId=45024L)/picklistOption"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='th_TH',optionId=45024L)",
                                    "type": "SFOData.PicklistLabel"
                                },
                                "optionId": "45024",
                                "locale": "th_TH",
                                "id": "177969",
                                "label": "Theft the company property",
                                "picklistOption": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='th_TH',optionId=45024L)/picklistOption"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "picklist": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistOption(45024L)/picklist"
                        }
                    },
                    "childPicklistOptions": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistOption(45024L)/childPicklistOptions"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistOption(45995L)",
                        "type": "SFOData.PicklistOption"
                    },
                    "id": "45995",
                    "minValue": "0",
                    "externalCode": "Transfer",
                    "maxValue": "0",
                    "optionValue": "-1",
                    "sortOrder": 40,
                    "mdfExternalCode": "Transfer",
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "parentPicklistOption": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistOption(45995L)/parentPicklistOption"
                        }
                    },
                    "picklistLabels": {
                        "results": [
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='th_TH',optionId=45995L)",
                                    "type": "SFOData.PicklistLabel"
                                },
                                "optionId": "45995",
                                "locale": "th_TH",
                                "id": "181793",
                                "label": "ลาออก โอนย้ายระหว่างภาค",
                                "picklistOption": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='th_TH',optionId=45995L)/picklistOption"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='en_GB',optionId=45995L)",
                                    "type": "SFOData.PicklistLabel"
                                },
                                "optionId": "45995",
                                "locale": "en_GB",
                                "id": "181791",
                                "label": "Resignation and Transfer across Region",
                                "picklistOption": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistLabel(locale='en_GB',optionId=45995L)/picklistOption"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "picklist": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistOption(45995L)/picklist"
                        }
                    },
                    "childPicklistOptions": {
                        "__deferred": {
                            "uri": "https://someapi.insomeplace.com/odata/v2/PicklistOption(45995L)/childPicklistOptions"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the schema and sample data for `jsonDF` dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial sample data:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|            optionId|               label|              locale|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      [45024, 45024]|[Theft the compan...|      [en_GB, en_US]|
|[45624, 45624, 45...|[Back to home tow...|[th_TH, en_US, en...|
|      [45048, 45048]|[Education, Educa...|      [en_TH, en_US]|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Since `d.optionId, d.label and d.locale` have values as arrays and the values of `d.optionId and d.label` are an array of same values. So, you can use `explode()` funtion again on `d.optionId and d.label` while using distinct to convert the array with same elements to just the value.

```
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select(explode(jsonDF2.optionId),jsonDF2.label,jsonDF2.locale).withColumnRenamed("col","optionId").distinct()
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select(jsonDF2.optionId,explode(jsonDF2.label),jsonDF2.locale).withColumnRenamed("col","label").distinct()
jsonDF2.show(100,truncate=False)

+--------+-----------------+---------------------+
|optionId|label            |locale               |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------+
|45624   |Back to home town|[th_TH, en_US, en_GB]|
|45048   |Education        |[en_TH, en_US]       |
|45024   |Theft the company|[en_GB, en_US]       |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Now your requirement is to get `d.locale` to also be a value using `filter()` function based on the condition that `en_GB` is in d.locale. Since you already know the value you are using to filter the dataframe, you can select only `d.optionId and d.lable` from jsonDF2 and insert the `d.locale` with 'en_GB' as its value. The following code will help:

```
solution_df = jsonDF2.select(jsonDF2.optionId, jsonDF2.label).filter(array_contains(col("locale"), "en_GB")).withColumn("locale", lit("en_GB"))
solution_df.show(truncate=False)

+--------+-----------------+------+
|optionId|label            |locale|
+--------+-----------------+------+
|45624   |Back to home town|en_GB |
|45024   |Theft the company|en_GB |
+--------+-----------------+------+
```

**Updated Code:**

```
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select(explode(col('optionId')),'`d.label`','`d.locale`').withColumnRenamed("col","optionId").distinct()
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select('optionId',explode(jsonDF2['`d.label`']),'`d.locale`').withColumnRenamed("col","d.label").distinct()

solution_df = jsonDF2.select('optionId', '`d.label`').filter(array_contains(col("`d.locale`"), "en_GB")).withColumn("d.locale", lit("en_GB"))
solution_df.show(truncate=False)
```

**Update #2:**
The better way for you to achieve your requirement is to convert the pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe and perform operations as shown below.

```
#same as your code

jsonDF2 = jsonDF.withColumn('d', explode(col('d.picklistOptions.results.picklistLabels.results')))

jsonDF2.printSchema()

#selecting the columns
jsonDF3 = jsonDF2.select(jsonDF2.d.optionId, jsonDF2.d.label,jsonDF2.d.locale)

#printing its schema
jsonDF3.show(truncate=False)

+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|d.optionId           |d.label                                                                             |d.locale             |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|[45024, 45024, 45024]|[Theft the company property, Theft the company property, Theft the company property]|[en_GB, en_US, th_TH]|
|[45995, 45995]       |[ลาออก โอนย้ายระหว่างภาค, Resignation and Transfer across Region]                   |[th_TH, en_GB]       |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Now convert the Pyspark dataframe to Pandas dataframe. Use `iterrows()` function of pandas dataframe to extract data as per the requirement.

```
jsonDF_pd= jsonDF3.toPandas()

final=[]
for i in jsonDF_pd.iterrows():
    list1=i[1][0]
    list2=i[1][1]
    list3=i[1][2]
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        final. append ([list1[i],list2[i],str(list3[i])])
#print(final)
#You can use this 'final' array as input data to create dataframe as below
cols = ['optionId','label','locale']
finalDF = spark.createDataFrame(final,cols)
finalDF.show()

+--------+--------------------+------+
|optionId|               label|locale|
+--------+--------------------+------+
|   45024|Theft the company...| en_GB|
|   45024|Theft the company...| en_US|
|   45024|Theft the company...| th_TH|
|   45995|ลาออก โอนย้ายระหว...| th_TH|
|   45995|Resignation and T...| en_GB|
+--------+--------------------+------+
```

Using filter:

```
finalDF.select('optionId','label','locale').filter(col('locale')=='en_GB').show(truncate=False)

+--------+--------------------------------------+------+
|optionId|label                                 |locale|
+--------+--------------------------------------+------+
|45024   |Theft the company property            |en_GB |
|45995   |Resignation and Transfer across Region|en_GB |
+--------+--------------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: Appreciated Saideep, please see above for my update.

Comment: Hey @Lynchie, Can you please include the schema for `jsonDF` dataframe in the question? Thanks.

Comment: Saideep I've added a screenshot above from Databricks.

Comment: Hey @Lynchie I have added the updated code. Please check if this new approach is working.

Comment: failed I'm afraid, I've decided to take an example of the JSON I'm using a post above for you, probably easier for you to work from what I'm working from. Obviously if you breakdown how you would my JSON, I can then work from that where my mistakes are being made, maybe the mistake is earlier on or how I'm dealing with the JSON itself.

Comment: Does the `d.label` field have different values for the same `optionId` (like in the json data where for optionId = 45995, there are 2 different values but for the rest, they all have same values)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245417/discussion-between-saideeparikontham-mt-and-lynchie).